# How to use cut properly to get the desired output from a string in shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, cut

```
#!/bin/bash
list="john,do not target
martin,unknown"

for i in $list; do
     name=`echo ${i} | cut -f1 -d','`
     value=`echo ${i} | cut -f2 -d','`
     echo $value
done
```

Because of the white space between do not target the output i am getting for the above is,

```
do
not
target
unknown
```

My desired output is:

```
do not target
unknown
```

Comment: `echo "$list" | cut -d ',' -f 2`?

Comment: Aside from the given answer, [BashFAQ/001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) might help. One of the flaws in your original implementation is that `$list` is subject to word splitting which breaks it apart on ALL whitespace by default, not just newlines.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: Note that `echo $value` is very unsafe.  `echo "$value"` is safer, but still unsafe.  Safe is `printf '%s\n' "$value"`.  See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812).

Answer (score 5):

No need for `cut` (an external process); you can do this in Bash:

```bash
list='john,do not target
martin,unknown'

while IFS= read -r line; do
    name="${line%%,*}"
    value="${line#*,}"
    printf "'%s' : '%s'\n" "$name" "$value"
done <<< "$list"
```

However, unless the `list` comes from an input beyond your control (in terms of format), there are better ways to represent such data in Bash, such as an associative array.

```bash
declare -A list=(
    ['john']='do not target'
    ['martin']='unknown'
)

for name in "${!list[@]}"; do
    printf "'%s' : '%s'\n" "$name" "${list["$name"]}"
done
```

Admittedly, an associative array does not preserve ordering; if that is desired you could have an additional (integer-indexed) array mapping from numbers to names.

```bash
declare -a list=('john' 'martin')
declare -A data=(
    ['john']='do not target'
    ['martin']='unknown'
)

for name in "${list[@]}"; do
    printf "'%s' : '%s'\n" "$name" "${data["$name"]}"
done
```

Answer (score 5):

Let `read` do the splitting for us (via `IFS`):

```
while IFS=, read -r name value      # split line of input on a comma; store 1st field in variable 'name', store rest of input in variable 'value'
do
    echo "${value}"
done <<< "${list}"
```

**NOTE:** this has the added benefit of eliminating the 4 subprocesses the current code spawns on each pass through the loop

This generates:

```
do not target
unknown
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the other answers, `bash` has facilities to deal with this type of problems, and you don't have to (and usually you shouldn't) call external utilities. Just to answer the question, or in case you insist on using `cut`, I'd suggest to use it like this:

```
list="john,do not target
martin,unknown"

cut -d, -f2 <<< "$list"
```

This prints out:

```
do not target
unknown
```

Answer (score 2):

Good answers here already, but take a moment to look at what you are doing.

```
list="john,do not target
martin,unknown"
```

This is not a list, it's a string - a single string, which you are using, unquoted, in your loop with

```
for i in $list; do
```

I'm pretty sure this is really not what you wanted.
When you say `$list` you are getting much the same as would be output by using it in an unquoted `echo` -

```
$: list="john,do not target
martin,unknown"
$: echo $list
john,do not target martin,unknown
```

So what you saying is

```
for i in john,do not target martin,unknown; do
```

So the first time i is "john,do". The second time it's "not". Etc.

A simple `read` will do what you are trying to do, I think.

```
$: echo "$list"
john,do not target
martin,unknown

$: echo "$list">file

$: while IFS=, read -r name value; do echo "name=[$name] value=[$value]"; done < file
name=[john] value=[do not target]
name=[martin] value=[unknown]

$: while IFS=, read -r name value; do echo "name=[$name] value=[$value]"; done <<< "$list"
name=[john] value=[do not target]
name=[martin] value=[unknown]
```

So, I'd say for a clean replication of what you asked, use [markp-fuso's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75857115/8656552), though for the actual literal result *implied* by the snippet you posted, I agree with [M. Nejat Aydin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75857762/8656552) - use a simple `cut`.